# bindParam with foreach strange results

Tags: php, mysql

Using the following to bind several parameters dynamically to a statement:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name", USER, PASSWORD);

$params = array(':date' => '2014-02-01',
                ':amount' => 40,
                ':type' => 1
                );

$query = "INSERT INTO entry (`date`, amount, type) VALUES (:date, :amount, :type)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
    $stmt->bindParam($param, $value);
}

$stmt->execute()
```

The code works but inserts the following into the table:
0000-00-00, 1.00, 1

What is going on here?

Comment: Table structure could be usefull.

Comment: try to add type of variable also like string(s) etc

Comment: Try `foreach ($params as $param => &$value)` instead of `foreach ($params as $param => $value)`. See Vili's comment on: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @ZZ-bb Nice, worked well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Vili's comment on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) use `foreach ($params as $param => &$value)` instead of `foreach ($params as $param => $value)`.

Adding variable types to dynamically added query parameters requires some extra steps.

BTW. You not are defining the `$params` array dynamically at least in your example code so this might work as well. Replace the whole `foreach` with:

```
$result = $stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: BTW: You're right, but this was just a minimal example. The `foreach` actually will be inside a method.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `data type` ,

Correct format for `PDOStatement::bindParam`, should be like this

```
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT); //note PDO::PARAM_INT here
```

EG,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO movies(filmName,
            filmDescription,
            filmImage,
            filmPrice,
            filmReview) VALUES (
            :filmName,
            :filmDescription,
            :filmImage,
            :filmPrice,
            :filmReview)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':filmName', $_POST['filmName'], PDO::PARAM_STR);      
$stmt->bindParam(':filmDescription', $_POST['filmDescription'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':filmImage', $_POST['filmImage'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
// use PARAM_STR although a number 
$stmt->bindParam(':filmPrice', $_POST['filmPrice'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':filmReview', $_POST['filmReview'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  

$stmt->execute();
```

[REFERENCE](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

[REFERENCE 2](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/)

Comment: Of course it's working. ZZ-bb's comment also worked.